# Various MP3 Files and MP4 Videos make an external hard drive click at some points in time

Tags: hard-drive, mp3, mp4

My external hard drive tends to drop the head and click while it plays 
MP3’s and videos; some videos do it, others not.

I ran a smart test on that drive with WD-Lifeguard these are the results.

[image]

The clicking sound comes one time all 3 minutes, sometimes 5. It only happens at certain files which are on the drive. Otherwise the drive works perfectly, no copy errors, nothing suspicious other than that.

To explain it more precisely which files cause these uncommon click sounds to the hard drive: 
videos i downloaded with youtube video downloader.
old mp4 media files from previous drives.
Some of them only. 
If i would redownload an old youtube file again and replace it, 
the clicking would be gone. 
I tested this on one file. It worked. 
The question is: are the files corrupt?
Is the hard drive infected?
Or is the hard drive defect?

I tried to copy—let’s say—one video and play it. The error is still there. The file continues to play but the click still happens.

The hard drive is able to play/copy/write any file without problems.
Most of the files it gives an error to are from my old hard drive which i copied them to. It only happens on media files, otherwise i can copy even large amounts of files without any click happening.

I'd really like to know what it is. A virus?

Anyone know’s what this might be?

Comment: Run a chkdsk /r on the hard drive, see if it finds any inconsistencies and repairs them, once this is done defragment the drive, see if the behavior stops or changes.

Comment: **** I DID A CHKDSK *** NO ERRORS FOUND *** CLICK STILL HAPPENS
I Bought this drive a week ago.

Comment: The drive might be overheating. use whatever you have to get SMART info on temperature, and the read error rate.

Comment: Did you defrag the drive?

Comment: yes i defrag it frequently.

Comment: it is a 2TB  WD [ELEMENTS] (portable) External USB 3:0 Drive connected to a Windows 7 Computer . It is not even hot. And also i Don't know how to check smart on External Drives.

Comment: is windows 7 able to see read write errors?

Comment: i installed the lifeguard software from WD, it show's no errors, everything is marked green.